# BeautifulSoup findall returning empty list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

So i'm very new to python and I'm trying to get data from a table from iso-ne.com/isoexpress/ using bs4 and urllib. Here's what I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen
website='http://www.iso-ne.com/isoexpress/'
html=urlopen(website).read().decode('utf-8')
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
table=soup.find('div', {'class': 'chart'})
rows=table.find_all('tr')
for tr in rows:
   col=tr.find_all('td')
    for td in col:
        text=td.find_all(class_='lmp-list-energy')
        print text
```

When I run this, I get 6 empty brackets:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

the data that I am trying to get is the Five Minute Real Time LMP price for the state of New Hampshire on the iso-ne website

Comment: I believe these items don't just exist before executing javascript. That's why you cannot get them this way

Answer (score 2):

The data are filled by javascript, which is not interpreted by beautifulsoup : you get the raw container.

What I would do (but I would check about legality and conditions...): look at requests done to the backend (e.g. by using the network mode on chrome)
=> you'll find something a call to http://iso-ne.com/ws/wsclient. Grab the parameter that your client is sending (cookies...) and replay the request (or fine-tune the parameters though trial and error).

Good luck (I did manage to replay the request for data from curl, so it should be doable in python)